# OFFSET using a GUID kind of ID

Tags: mysql

I would like use the `OFFSET` in a SELECT query so I can use pagination in my webapplication. The only problem is I only know the ID of the row from which I would like to start, not the actually OFFSET. An ID looks like this: `asdfasfdf894t54yrqewrqew`.

So what I do, I SELECT all results from a table and ORDER it by the `created_at` column and set the LIMIT to a certain value. Now I only know the last ID I get returned, so I would like to start the next page from that ID.

Anyone who knows an easy way to accomplish this using a MySQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `offset` - it has to read all the rows to skip them.

If you order rows for pagination by `created_at`, then thats the column you need to use.

First page:

```
SELECT ... FROM table
ORDER BY created_at, id
LIMIT N + 1;
```

The `+1` gives you a peek to the next page - you can quickly decide if next page exists and where does it start. If `created_at` is not guaranteed to be unique, adding the ID to the ordering helps keep it stable.

Next page:

```
SELECT ... FROM table
WHERE created_at >= <(x+1)th created_at from previous page>
    AND id >= <(x+1)th id from previous page>
ORDER BY created_at, id
LIMIT N + 1;
```

You use the extra item from fetching the previous page to quickly find the start of current page using the ordering index to get new page.

Comment: Thanks a lot! created_at is not unique indeed, which caused some trouble, but adding the id that way is a nice solution :)

Comment: [More discussion](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).